# Error in connector: missing field `info` - Prisma Introspection (npx prisma db pull)

Tags: mongodb, azure-cosmosdb, prisma, prisma-graphql, prisma2

I have created an Express, Apollo GraphQL server which accepts requests and returns data from a MongoDB database via Prisma.

I have tested my application with a simple database from MongoDB Atlas and it all seems to work fine.

Now that I know everything works fine, I want to 'plug in' a MongoDB database which contains a lot of data already, located in my Azure portal (Cosmos DB).

I have changed the database connection string to point to this new database (a read only connection string) and now attempting to use the `Introspection` feature of Prisma (https://www.prisma.io/docs/getting-started/setup-prisma/add-to-existing-project/mongodb/introspection-typescript-mongodb#introspecting-mongodb-with-prisma).

After running the `npx prisma db pull --force` command, I get the following error:
[image]

I can't figure out if this is an issue with my connection string, or something else.
I have also attempted to use the Read/ Write connection string but that doesn't seem to work either. I get the same error message.

There does not seem to be any information online regarding this error message other than this:
https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/error-reference#prismaclientvalidationerror

But I am unsure if this is at all related, because it seems to relate to creating a new record, rather than anything to do with introspection.

Comment: I'm not sure Prisma officially supports CosmosDB and it definitely hasn't been tested thoroughly.